# getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) gives NullPOinterException

Tags: java, android, android-activity

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` gives `NullPOinterException`, Ever after I tried various combinations of

1. Activities (`AppComatActivity`),
2. Themes(`Theme.AppCompat.Light`, `Theme.Holo.Light`) and
3. Up button APIs(`getSupportActionBar()`, `getActionBar()`)

I know this question had been asked many times, But believe me none of their solution worked for me.

### My Motto:

I am just trying to set the Up button for my Child Activity.

### Preconditions I have set:

I have set the following in Manifest file for the Child Activity

```
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.sony.myfirstapplication.MainActivity">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.sony.myfirstapplication.MainActivity"
            />
```

and following code in my child activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_message);

    //receive message
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_msg_show);
    String msg = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    txt.setText(msg);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //Gives NullPointerException
}
```

Theme in manifest file:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Style declared in Style.xml file :-

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

### Note

I have inherited both Activities from `AppCompatActivity` and not `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: Does it WARN you about a nullPointerExcepction or does it crash at runtime?

Comment: Also please include the theme and style you're using for your activity

Comment: @AbAppletic : Yes Its Warning, Did not tried on hardware/emulator.
Yes I have tried Including both themes(mentioned above) one by one, but no one works.

Answer (score 2):

You should set your toolbar first:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
setSupportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I have tried this, it did not work directly, I need to change theme to NoActionBar, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said it doesn't **CRASH**, then simply add:    `@SuppressWarnings("null")` above that line.

Otherwise, add this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

First

Comment: If the IDE is saying that there will Exception, that means that it will crash, right?
I tried on hardware it crashed,

Comment: AS says "x may produce 'NullPointerException". Sometimes that's it. But sometimes you should add what I said. Have you tried anything

Comment: Yes I tried with Toolbar, I just need to change my theme in manifest to NoActionBar, then it worked.

Comment: I have one query:
If AppCompatActivity already supporting ActionBar then why we need to separately create Toolbar object and set it as SupportActionBar UNLIKE ActionBarActivity, In which method getActionBar() is enough.

Comment: Toolbar is an ordinary view. You add it into your activity.  You can add a textview above it, etc. It is much more flexible since YOU control it.

Comment: You need to setSupportActionBar since the activity needs to know WHAT is your toolbar. Unlike getActionBar(), YOU add the toolbar. ActionBarActivity on the other hand adds the actionbar for you, which makes it hard to do many things such as centering the title, changing title color, etc

Comment: If I solved your answer, please upvote and select my answer as the correct one. This will add to your rep and will add to mine, and will also help future visitors.